# ActionBarSherlock Beginners Setup Error

Tags: android, eclipse, actionbarsherlock

I am attempting to set up ActionBarShelock for the first time using Eclipse on Windows 7.

I followed these instructions: http://actionbarsherlock.com/usage.html

ActionBarSherlock project.properties:

```
    android.library=true
    # Project target.
    target=android-15
```

ActionBarSherlock AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="11"/>
```

My error in Lint: `Call requires API level 11 (current min is 7): android.widget...`

Or if I ignore the error on ActionBarSherlock and import it as a library then I cannot compile my project because any references to the library are not recognized and I get no resource errors.

I looked up many people with similar problems and it was always an API build target error.  Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: What call is the error talking about?

Comment: The call errors reference methods used in ActionBarSherlock classes that I am assuming are for api level 11

Comment: Can you give an example of such method?

Comment: In src.com.actionbarsherlock.app.sherlockactivity.java onActionModeStarted(ActionMode mode){} and onActionModeFinished(ActionMode mode){} have @Override tags but have the error "Must override superclass method".  This is one of the most common of the 327 Errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it! The JDK compliance level was set to 1.5. After setting it to 1.6 it worked.

It says this right in the Action Bar Sherlock website in the requirements section but I made the error of assuming Eclipse was using the latest JDK settings.

Definite beginners mistake.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

A few things:

1. Make sure you are compiling **your** application with Android 4.0 or newer (API 14+). You must do this in addition to just the library.
2. Ensure you are calling `getSupportActionBar` rather than `getActionBar`. This is likely the source of your errors for lint.
3. While targeting API 11 is valid, many things are gained by targeting 14 or higher. Try to do that if you can.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using an old version of ActionBarSherlock perhaps? As the current version, 4.1.0 has the targetSdk set to 15.

I think some older version can have a problem with newer ADT/lint or similar.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but I tried the latest version first and then the older versions.

Comment: yes my ADT is fully up to date. Maybe I will have to try this on a different machine.

Comment: The usual clean project (including yours, but most of all actionbarsherlock) is Worth to try as well.

Comment: Well and don't forget to try and clear the lint markers (android Tools entry when right clicking the actionbarsherlock project). It works fine for me with actionbarsherlock 4.1.0 and latest ADT.